# Inconsistent Breakpoints VSCode and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Given the following folder structure.

```
+ frontend
  + CreateReport
    + CreateReportInteractor.spec.ts
    + CreateReportInteractor.ts
+ tmp
  + frontend
    + CreateReportInteractor.js
    + CreateReportInteractor.js.map
    + CreateReportInteractor.spec.js
    + CreateReportInteractor.spec.js.map
```

I have a `node` script (unittests/tester.js) to execute my tests. These are loading the correct files (`tmp/frontend/*.spec.js`).

`node --inspect=9229 --debug-brk unittests/tester.js`

Inside `launch.json` I have the following attach request.

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",
    "port": 9229
}
```

This will attach to the executing code. It will break upon entry into the first line too.

My .scripts output from the debugger is:

```
› <>/tmp/frontend/CreateReport/CreateReportInteractor.js
    - ../../../frontend/CreateReport/CreateReportInteractor.ts (<>/frontend/CreateReport/CreateReportInteractor.ts)
› <>/tmp/frontend/CreateReport/CreateReportInteractor.spec.js
    - ../../../frontend/CreateReport/CreateReportInteractor.spec.ts (<>/frontend/CreateReport/CreateReportInteractor.spec.ts)
› <>/tmp/frontend/app/Const.js
    - ../../../frontend/app/Const.ts (<>/frontend/app/Const.ts)
› <>/tmp/frontend/app/Requests/MockRequest.helper.spec.js
    - ../../../../frontend/app/Requests/MockRequest.helper.spec.ts (<>/frontend/app/Requests/MockRequest.helper.spec.ts)
› <>/tmp/frontend/app/Requests/MockRequestFactory.helper.spec.js
    - ../../../../frontend/app/Requests/MockRequestFactory.helper.spec.ts (<>/frontend/app/Requests/MockRequestFactory.helper.spec.ts)
› <>/tmp/frontend/app/Requests/Request.js
    - ../../../../frontend/app/Requests/Request.ts (<>/frontend/app/Requests/Request.ts)
› <>/tmp/frontend/app/Requests/RequestFactory.js
    - ../../../../frontend/app/Requests/RequestFactory.ts (<>/frontend/app/Requests/RequestFactory.ts)
```

However, if I place a breakpoint in VSCode (red dot), sometimes it will stop execution and other times it will not.

If I place a `debugger;` statement, it will always stop execution.

If I place a VSCode breakpoint after a `debugger;` statement, it will always stop execution.

My version of VSCode is 1.19.2, Node is v6.9.4, and TypeScript is 2.6.2.

Please let me know if there is any advice you can give. I've been banging my head for the last 2 hours.